# Heisenberg group is nilpotent

Tags: solvable-groups, nilpotent-groups, heisenberg-group

$F$ is a field and $H(F)$ is the Heisenberg group over $F$. Is it nilpotent? Is it solvable?

I did all the math and I found that the commutator subgroup is in the center $Z(H(F))$, so $H(F)/Z(H(F))$ is abelian. The only thing I have to do is to show that $Z(H(F)/Z(H(F)))=Z_{2}(H(F))=H(F)$ so $H(F)$ nilpotent. Is it obvious that $Z(H(F)/Z(H(F)))=Z_{2}(H(F))=H(F)$? What should I say?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already proved that the commutator subgroup is in the center, you can conclude that the group is nilpotent of class 2 since it is not abelian.

Comment: Could you explain it a little bit more, please?

Comment: What do you need explained?

Comment: Can I always say that if the commutator subgroup is in the center, then the group is nilpotent?

Comment: Yes, if $[G,G]<Z(G)$ then the group is nilpotent of class at most 2. This can be deduced from any definition of nilpotent groups (using lower or upper central series).

Comment: thank you very much!